# Fill a DropDownList with an Enum which has a value = -1, and place it in first position

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, enums, html.dropdownlistfor, dropdownlistfor

I'm working with `ASP.NET MVC3` and I'm trying to fill a `DropDownList` with an `Enum`.
My problem is that the enum begins at `-1` and the `DropDownList` is correctly filled, but the first item (whichever has the `-1` value) is always the last item of my `DropDownList` ; however, I need it in first position.

Here is my `.cshtml`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyEnumMax, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))), new { @id = "myId", @class = "myClass" })
```

Here, `MyEnumMax` is a string property representing a `MyEnum` member (maybe is this the problem ? However, it really helps me elsewhere in the project to have this string property)

and the enum just looks like

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Undefined = -1,
    Member1,
    Member 2
}
```

So in my view, I have my ddl lloks like :

- Member1
- Member2
- Undefined

whereas I need :

- Undefined
- Member1
- Member2

I tried some `OrderBy(x => x.Value)` but it doesn't care and still displays *Undefined* at last position.
Any help (**with code sample**) appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to order Enum by its int value,

code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TestEnumValue,Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
.Cast<MyEnum>()
.OrderBy(e => (int)e)
.Select(e => new  SelectListItem 
{ 
    Text  = e.ToString(), 
    Value  = ((int)e).ToString()
} ))
```

You also need to cast GetValues to get typed version: `GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>`

result:

[image]